# Managing "nested" group in Ansible YAML inventory files

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I'm managing a number of clusters, and I wanted to consolidate multiple inventory files into a single inventory that looks effectively like this:

```yaml
all:
  children:
    cluster_one:
      children:
        controller:
          hosts:
            host1:
            host2:
            host3:
        compute:
          hosts:
            host4:
            host5:
            host6:
    cluster_two:
      children:
        controller:
          hosts:
            host11:
            host12:
            host13:
```

I was expecting this to end up parsed like this:

```ini
[cluster_one]
host1
host2
host3
host4
host5
host6

[cluster_two]
host11
host12
host13

[controller]
host1
host2
host3
host11
host12
host13

[compute]
host4
host5
host6
```

With that structure, I would be able to ask for "controllers in
cluster_one"  with the host pattern `cluster_one:&controller`, or if
I wanted all controllers across all clusters I could just ask for
`controller`.  Convenient!

Unfortunately, it's actually parsed like this:

```ini
[cluster_one]
host1
host2
host3
host4
host5
host6

[cluster_two]
host11
host12
host13

[controller]
host1
host2
host3
host11
host12
host13

[compute]
host4
host5
host6

[cluster_one:children]
controller
compute

[cluster_two:children]
controller
```

Note the two extra entries at the bottom that make the `controller`
and `compute` groups children of their respecting "parents" in the
YAML file, rather than making only their *hosts* members of the
parents.

So for example if I run `ansible -i example.yml --list-hosts cluster_one`, I get:

```
  hosts (9):
    host1
    host2
    host3
    host11
    host12
    host13
    host4
    host5
    host6
```

That was unexpected and made me sad. I can obviously restructure the
inventory so that it works (e.g. by using the INI-format inventory
shown here, or re-structuring the YAML for a similar structure), but
those solutions involve listing each host multiple times, which means
it's possible for things to get out of sync.

Is there a way to structure the inventory that gets me the grouping I
want without having to explicitly list hosts in multiple groups?

Comment: I think you have a typo on the results of `--list-hosts`. `host10` should be `host13` ?

Answer (score 5):

***Building up on input in latest @larsk's answer with the `constructed` inventory plugin. Original answer below***

---

There is a possibility to DRY a bit more with the constructed plugin if you keep the same naming convention for cluster groups/subgroups, eliminating the need to introduce an additional variable in the groups.

Note that using convention for file names inside the inventory dir allows for natural loading order of the inventory sources as well without having to modify `ansible.cfg`

Given the following minimal `inventories/cluster/cluster.yml` static inventory source:

```yaml
---
all:
  children:
    cluster_one:
      children:
        cluster_one_controller:
          hosts:
            host1:
            host2:
            host3:
        cluster_one_compute:
          hosts:
            host4:
            host5:
            host6:
    cluster_two:
      children:
        cluster_two_controller:
          hosts:
            host11:
            host12:
            host13:
```

And the corresponding `inventories/cluster/cluster_constructed.yml` dynamic inventory source based on existing group names detection:

```yaml
---
plugin: constructed
strict: false
groups:
  controller: group_names | select('match', '^.*_controller$') | length > 0
  compute: group_names | select('match', '^.*_compute$') | length > 0
```

We get the expected result using our composite inventory directory

```
$ ansible-inventory -i inventories/cluster --list
{
    "_meta": {
        "hostvars": {}
    },
    "all": {
        "children": [
            "cluster_one",
            "cluster_two",
            "compute",
            "controller",
            "ungrouped"
        ]
    },
    "cluster_one": {
        "children": [
            "cluster_one_compute",
            "cluster_one_controller"
        ]
    },
    "cluster_one_compute": {
        "hosts": [
            "host4",
            "host5",
            "host6"
        ]
    },
    "cluster_one_controller": {
        "hosts": [
            "host1",
            "host2",
            "host3"
        ]
    },
    "cluster_two": {
        "children": [
            "cluster_two_controller"
        ]
    },
    "cluster_two_controller": {
        "hosts": [
            "host11",
            "host12",
            "host13"
        ]
    },
    "compute": {
        "hosts": [
            "host4",
            "host5",
            "host6"
        ]
    },
    "controller": {
        "hosts": [
            "host1",
            "host11",
            "host12",
            "host13",
            "host2",
            "host3"
        ]
    }
}
```

***original answer***

---

I'm deeply sorry this made you sad @larks. Unfortunately, as you just experienced:

- the content of the group does not depend on the place where you define it and will at the end be a consolidation of all hosts/children definitions.
- the group defined as a children anywhere will contain all the hosts defined elsewhere.

The only static yaml inventory definition I can think of that gets as close to your initial requirement and  respects the DRY principle as much as possible is:

```yaml
---
all:
  children:
    cluster_one:
      children:
        cluster_one_controller:
          hosts:
            host1:
            host2:
            host3:
        cluster_one_compute:
          hosts:
            host4:
            host5:
            host6:
    cluster_two:
      children:
        cluster_two_controller:
          hosts:
            host11:
            host12:
            host13:
    controller:
      children:
        cluster_one_controller:
        cluster_two_controller:
    compute:
      children:
        controller_one_compute:
```

This will let you select any of the following patterns (non exhaustive list):

- a full cluster e.g. `cluster_one`
- all controllers of a cluster e.g `cluster_two_controller` or `cluster_two:&controller`
- all compute nodes across clusters e.g. `compute`
- ...

Hope this will help to shine some light on your day (or night...)

Answer (score 3):

By using an inventory layout similar to what @Zeitounator suggested
and making use of the `constructed` inventory plugin, I've been able
to get what I want. I start with a static inventory in
`inventory/static/clusters.yml` that looks like:

```yaml
all:
  children:
    cluster_one:
      children:
        cluster_one_controller:
          vars:
            node_role: controller
          hosts:
            host1:
            host2:
            host3:
        cluster_one_compute:
          vars:
            node_role: compute
          hosts:
            host4:
            host5:
            host6:
    cluster_two:
      children:
        cluster_two_controller:
          vars:
            node_role: controller
          hosts:
            host11:
            host12:
            host13:
```

Then I mix in the following inventory from
`inventory/dynamic/constructed.yml`:

```yaml
plugin: constructed
strict: false
keyed_groups:
  - prefix: ""
    separator: ""
    key: node_role
```

And an `ansible.cfg` that looks like:

```ini
[defaults]
inventory = inventory/static,inventory/dynamic
```

(That ensures the `constructed` inventory loads *after* the static
inventory, without mucking about trying to manually order filenames).

---

With the above in place, I can run a task on just `cluster_one`:

```
ansible cluster_one ...
```

Or on all controllers:

```
ansible controller ...
```

Or just on controllers in `cluster_two`:

```
ansible 'cluster_two:&controller' ...
```

Etc.

(For that last example I can of course write `cluster_two_controller`
instead of `cluster_two:&controller`, but I like the intersection
syntax because it matches my mental map of what I'm trying to do.)

Answer (score 2):

How much does it take to code it in a play? Given the structure in the dictionary

```yaml
shell> cat _hosts
all:
  cluster_one:
    controller:
      - host1
      - host2
      - host3
    compute:
      - host4
      - host5
      - host6
  cluster_two:
    controller:
      - host11
      - host12
      - host13
```

The play creates the dictionary of the groups

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    inv: "{{ lookup('file', '_hosts')|from_yaml }}"
  tasks:
    - name: all
      set_fact:
        _groups: "{{ _groups|d({})|combine({'all': _hosts}) }}"
      vars:
        _hosts: "{{ inv.all|json_query('*.*')|flatten }}"
    - name: clusters
      set_fact:
        _groups: "{{ _groups|combine({item: _hosts}) }}"
      loop: "{{ inv.all.keys()|list }}"
      vars:
        _hosts: "{{ inv.all|json_query(item ~ '.*')|flatten }}"
    - name: sub_clusters
      set_fact:
        _groups: "{{ _groups|combine(item, list_merge='append') }}"
      loop: "{{ inv.all|json_query('*') }}"
    - debug:
        var: _groups
```

gives

```yaml
  _groups:
    all:
    - host1
    - host2
    - host3
    - host4
    - host5
    - host6
    - host11
    - host12
    - host13
    cluster_one:
    - host1
    - host2
    - host3
    - host4
    - host5
    - host6
    cluster_two:
    - host11
    - host12
    - host13
    compute:
    - host4
    - host5
    - host6
    controller:
    - host1
    - host2
    - host3
    - host11
    - host12
    - host13
```

Then create the groups

```yaml
    - add_host:
        name: "{{ item.1 }}"
        groups: "{{ item.0.key }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ _groups|dict2items }}"
        - value
    - debug:
        var: groups
```

gives

```yaml
  groups:
    all:
    - host1
    - host2
    - host3
    - host4
    - host5
    - host6
    - host11
    - host12
    - host13
    cluster_one:
    - host1
    - host2
    - host3
    - host4
    - host5
    - host6
    cluster_two:
    - host11
    - host12
    - host13
    compute:
    - host4
    - host5
    - host6
    controller:
    - host1
    - host2
    - host3
    - host11
    - host12
    - host13
    ungrouped: []
```