# Ansible playbook running in non-wanted servers

Tags: ansible

I just created a couple of playbooks and they require running in different hosts, depending on the task.

To do this, I created this hosts.yml file:

```
all:
  hosts:
    localhost:
      ansible_connection: local
      ansible_python_interpreter: auto
    foo-a-emea:
      ansible_connection: ssh
      ansible_user: ec2-user
      ansible_ssh_private_key_file: ~/.ssh/id_rsa
      ansible_host: <host address>
    foo-b-emea:
      ansible_connection: ssh
      ansible_user: ec2-user
      ansible_ssh_private_key_file: ~/.ssh/id_rsa
      ansible_host: <host address>
    foo-a-us:
      ansible_connection: ssh
      ansible_user: ec2-user
      ansible_ssh_private_key_file: ~/.ssh/id_rsa
      ansible_host: <host address>
    foo-b-us:
      ansible_connection: ssh
      ansible_user: ec2-user
      ansible_ssh_private_key_file: ~/.ssh/id_rsa
      ansible_host: <host address>
    bar-emea:
      ansible_connection: ssh
      ansible_user: ubuntu
      ansible_ssh_private_key_file: ~/.ssh/id_rsa
      ansible_host: <host address>
      ansible_python_interpreter: auto
    bar-us:
      ansible_connection: ssh
      ansible_user: ec2-user
      ansible_ssh_private_key_file: ~/.ssh/id_rsa
      ansible_host: <host address>
      ansible_python_interpreter: auto
  children:
    ec2:
      children:
        foo:
          children:
            emea:
              hosts:
                foo-a-emea:
                foo-b-emea:
            us:
              hosts:
                foo-a-us:
                foo-b-us:
        bar:
          children:
            emea:
              hosts:
                bar-emea:
            us:
              hosts:
                bar-us:
```

In my playbook I have this:

```
- hosts: foo
  roles:
    - role: sync
```

But, when the playbook is executing is running the sync role in both 'foo' and 'bar' servers and not only in the 'foo' ones as I was expecting.

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: What would you expect when ``- hosts: us``?

Comment: They are separated because i have different configurations for each hub, namely other services that requires connection, let's say SNS, or Route 53 Zones, for example. This way I create in the group_vars a file named emea.yaml and us.yaml to have the different local configurations there.

Comment: And? What is the answer to the question?

Comment: I was expecting to act on all hosts in the US group. As you can see in my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized having 2 subgroups with the same name makes ansible to do some confusion. Reorganizing to this example it will solve myu problem the way I really need. I leave here the solution to help others:

```
  children:
    ec2:
      children:
        foo:
          hosts:
            foo-a-emea:
            foo-b-emea:
            foo-a-us:
            foo-b-us:
        bar:
          hosts:
            bar-emea:
            bar-us:
        emea:
          hosts:
            foo-a-emea:
            foo-b-emea:
            bar-emea:
         us:
          hosts:
            foo-a-us:
            foo-b-us:
            bar-us:
```

Comment: Dup https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69494518/ansible-playbook-running-in-non-wanted-servers/69495904#69495904

Comment: You might want to look at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68746910/9401096) and given answers for a dynamic way to sort your subgroup problem

Answer (score 1):

Q: **"*What did I do wrong here?*"**

A: Nothing. The result is as expected. To prove it, limit the inventory to the relevant part

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
all:
  children:
    ec2:
      children:
        foo:
          children:
            emea:
              hosts:
                foo-a-emea:
                foo-b-emea:
            us:
              hosts:
                foo-a-us:
                foo-b-us:
        bar:
          children:
            emea:
              hosts:
                bar-emea:
            us:
              hosts:
                bar-us:
```

Display the graph

```yaml
shell> ansible-inventory -i hosts --graph
@all:
  |--@ec2:
  |  |--@bar:
  |  |  |--@emea:
  |  |  |  |--bar-emea
  |  |  |  |--foo-a-emea
  |  |  |  |--foo-b-emea
  |  |  |--@us:
  |  |  |  |--bar-us
  |  |  |  |--foo-a-us
  |  |  |  |--foo-b-us
  |  |--@foo:
  |  |  |--@emea:
  |  |  |  |--bar-emea
  |  |  |  |--foo-a-emea
  |  |  |  |--foo-b-emea
  |  |  |--@us:
  |  |  |  |--bar-us
  |  |  |  |--foo-a-us
  |  |  |  |--foo-b-us
  |--@ungrouped:
```

You can see that the members of the groups were merged. (If you think it's ambiguous try to answer the question "What would you expect when *- hosts: us*?")

Quoting from the documentation. ["*Child groups have a couple of properties to note:*"](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#inheriting-variable-values-group-variables-for-groups-of-groups)

> - Any host that is member of a child group is automatically a member of the parent group.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I didn't know about that command and it helped me to see my mistake. Because I had the same group name in 2 different child groups, ansible was making some confusion. Marking your as the answer but putting here my solution also.

Comment: I haven't noticed any of Ansible's confusion. Have you?