# Ansible nested group_vars (use only if member in group A and B)

Tags: ansible, var, ansible-inventory

My Inventory is nested like so:

```yaml
customerA:
  children:
    webserver:
      hosts:
        host1:
        host2:
    dbserver:
      hosts:
        host3:
        host4:
customerB:
  children:
    webserver:
      hosts:
        host5:
        host6:
    dbserver:
      hosts:
        host7:
        host8:
```

So for `host1` ansible loads:

```
host_vars/host1
group_vars/customerA
group_vars/webserver
```

Is there a way to create a `nested_vars/customerA/webserver.yml` (same as `nested_vars/webserver/customerA.yml`) structure that gets used by the inventory management?

Or do I have to use something like

```
group_vars/customerA
- parent: "customerA"
  
group_vars/webserver:
- child: "webserver"
```

in every playbook:

```yaml
include_vars:
  file: "{{ parent }}+{{ child }}.yml"
```

or create new groups for all combinations I need to target?

Answer (score 4):

*This is built upon [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68746910/managing-nested-group-in-ansible-yaml-inventory-files/68749778#68749778)*

---

Create your base static inventory

**`inventories/default/0-hosts.yml`**

```yaml
---
customerA:
  children:
    customerA_webservers:
      hosts:
        host1:
        host2:
    customerA_dbservers:
      hosts:
        host3:
        host4:
customerB:
  children:
    customerB_webservers:
      hosts:
        host5:
        host6:
    customerB_dbservers:
      hosts:
        host7:
        host8:
```

Make your type groups (e.g. `webservers`, `dbservers`) dynamic using the above naming convention with the [constructed inventory plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/constructed_inventory.html)

**`inventories/default/1-typegroups_constructed.yml`**

```yaml
---
plugin: constructed
groups:
  dbservers: group_names | select('match', '^.*_dbservers$') | length > 0
  webservers: group_names | select('match', '^.*_webservers$') | length > 0
```

You now have a complete fine grained group membership:

```
$ ansible-inventory -i inventories/default/ --list
{
    "_meta": {
        "hostvars": {}
    },
    "all": {
        "children": [
            "ungrouped",
            "customerA",
            "customerB",
            "webservers",
            "dbservers"
        ]
    },
    "customerA": {
        "children": [
            "customerA_webservers",
            "customerA_dbservers"
        ]
    },
    "customerA_dbservers": {
        "hosts": [
            "host3",
            "host4"
        ]
    },
    "customerA_webservers": {
        "hosts": [
            "host1",
            "host2"
        ]
    },
    "customerB": {
        "children": [
            "customerB_webservers",
            "customerB_dbservers"
        ]
    },
    "customerB_dbservers": {
        "hosts": [
            "host7",
            "host8"
        ]
    },
    "customerB_webservers": {
        "hosts": [
            "host5",
            "host6"
        ]
    },
    "dbservers": {
        "hosts": [
            "host3",
            "host4",
            "host7",
            "host8"
        ]
    },
    "webservers": {
        "hosts": [
            "host1",
            "host2",
            "host5",
            "host6"
        ]
    }
}
```

Which makes you able to address:

- variables for a customer in e.g.:

  ```
  inventories/default/group_vars/customerA.yml
  ```
- variables for a server type in e.g.:

  ```
  inventories/default/group_vars/dbservers.yml
  ```
- variables for a server type for one customer in e.g.:

  ```
  inventories/default/group_vars/customerB_webservers.yml
  ```

Answer (score 2):

In your question, you say that *host1* loads:

```
host_vars/host1
group_vars/customerA
group_vars/webserver
```

This is not complete. *host1* also loads *group_vars/customerB*. To prove it run the playbook below

```yaml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: groups|to_yaml
      run_once: true
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  groups:
    all: [host1, host2, host5, host6, host3, host4, host7, host8]
    customerA: [host1, host2, host5, host6, host3, host4, host7, host8]
    customerB: [host1, host2, host5, host6, host3, host4, host7, host8]
    dbserver: [host3, host4, host7, host8]
    ungrouped: []
    webserver: [host1, host2, host5, host6]
```

The structure of Ansible inventory is flat. All hosts are members of either *dbserver* or *webserver*. Both *dbserver* and *webserver* and members of *customerA* and *customerB*. Consequently, all hosts are members of *customerA* and *customerB*.

---

**Limit the members of *customerA* and *customerB***

Declare the variables below. Fit the source of the inventory (*nv_inv*)

```yaml
  nv_inv: "{{ lookup('file', 'hosts')|from_yaml }}"
  nv_groups_0_keys: "{{ nv_inv|json_query('keys(@)') }}"
  nv_groups_0_vals: "{{ nv_inv|json_query('*.children[].*.keys(hosts)')|map('flatten') }}"
  nv_groups_0: "{{ dict(nv_groups_0_keys|zip(nv_groups_0_vals)) }}"
  nv_groups: "{{ groups|combine(nv_groups_0) }}"
  nv_hosts_str: |
    {% for h in nv_groups.all %}
    {{ h }}: {{ nv_groups|dict2items|selectattr('value', 'contains', h)|map(attribute='key')|sort }}
    {% endfor %}
  nv_hosts: "{{ nv_hosts_str|from_yaml }}"
```

This will create your dictionary of groups

```yaml
  nv_groups:
    all: [host1, host2, host5, host6, host3, host4, host7, host8]
    customerA: [host1, host2, host3, host4]
    customerB: [host5, host6, host7, host8]
    dbserver: [host3, host4, host7, host8]
    ungrouped: []
    webserver: [host1, host2, host5, host6]
```

and hosts

```yaml
  nv_hosts:
    host1: [all, customerA, webserver]
    host2: [all, customerA, webserver]
    host3: [all, customerA, dbserver]
    host4: [all, customerA, dbserver]
    host5: [all, customerB, webserver]
    host6: [all, customerB, webserver]
    host7: [all, customerB, dbserver]
    host8: [all, customerB, dbserver]
```

**Nested variables**

You can create such a framework on your own. For example, create the files below. Each filename is a dash-separated list of the groups. To include the file, a host must be a member of all groups in the filename. The order of the groups in a filename is not significant. The file *all.yml* will work as expected. The matching files will overwrite each other in alphabetical order (*query('fileglob', nv_glob)*).

```bash
shell> tree nested_vars/
nested_vars/
├── dbserver-customerB.yml
├── webserver-customerA.yml
└── webserver-customerB.yml

0 directories, 3 files
```

```yaml
shell> cat nested_vars/dbserver-customerB.yml 
test_var: dbserver,customerB
```

```yaml
shell> cat nested_vars/webserver-customerA.yml 
test_var: webserver,customerA
```

```yaml
shell> cat nested_vars/webserver-customerB.yml 
test_var: webserver,customerB
```

Declare the variables below. Fit the path and pattern (*nv_glob*)

```yaml
  nv_glob: "{{ playbook_dir }}/nested_vars/*.yml"
  nv_files: "{{ query('fileglob', nv_glob) }}"
  nv_files_groups: "{{ nv_files|map('basename')|map('splitext')|map('first')|map('split', '-') }}"
  nv_files_dict: "{{ dict(nv_files|zip(nv_files_groups)) }}"
  nv_files_list: "{{ nv_files_dict|dict2items(key_name='file', value_name='groups') }}"
```

This will create the list of the files

```yaml
  nv_files_list:
    - file: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-220/nested_vars/webserver-customerA.yml
      groups: [webserver, customerA]
    - file: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-220/nested_vars/webserver-customerB.yml
      groups: [webserver, customerB]
    - file: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-220/nested_vars/dbserver-customerB.yml
      groups: [dbserver, customerB]
```

Include the files from *nested_vars*

```yaml
  - include_vars: "{{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ nv_files_list|
              selectattr('groups', 'subset', nv_hosts[inventory_hostname])|
              map(attribute='file')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [include_vars] **************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => (item=/export/scratch/tmp7/test-220/nested_vars/webserver-customerA.yml)
ok: [host2] => (item=/export/scratch/tmp7/test-220/nested_vars/webserver-customerA.yml)
ok: [host6] => (item=/export/scratch/tmp7/test-220/nested_vars/webserver-customerB.yml)
ok: [host5] => (item=/export/scratch/tmp7/test-220/nested_vars/webserver-customerB.yml)
skipping: [host3]
ok: [host7] => (item=/export/scratch/tmp7/test-220/nested_vars/dbserver-customerB.yml)
skipping: [host4]
ok: [host8] => (item=/export/scratch/tmp7/test-220/nested_vars/dbserver-customerB.yml)
```

Test it

```yaml
  - debug:
      var: test_var
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => 
  test_var: webserver,customerA
ok: [host5] => 
  test_var: webserver,customerB
ok: [host2] => 
  test_var: webserver,customerA
ok: [host6] => 
  test_var: webserver,customerB
ok: [host3] => 
  test_var: VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!
ok: [host4] => 
  test_var: VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!
ok: [host7] => 
  test_var: dbserver,customerB
ok: [host8] => 
  test_var: dbserver,customerB
```

---

Example of a complete project for testing

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── group_vars
│   └── all
│       ├── nv_files.yml
│       └── nv_hosts.yml
├── hosts
├── nested_vars
│   ├── dbserver-customerB.yml
│   ├── webserver-customerA.yml
│   └── webserver-customerB.yml
└── pb.yml

3 directories, 8 files
```

```ini
shell> cat ansible.cfg 
[defaults]
gathering = explicit
collections_path = $HOME/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/
inventory = $PWD/hosts
roles_path = $PWD/roles
retry_files_enabled = false
stdout_callback = yaml
```

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
customerA:
  children:
    webserver:
      hosts:
        host1:
        host2:
    dbserver:
      hosts:
        host3:
        host4:
customerB:
  children:
    webserver:
      hosts:
        host5:
        host6:
    dbserver:
      hosts:
        host7:
        host8:
```

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: all

  pre_tasks:

    - block:
        - debug:
            var: nv_inv
        - debug:
            var: nv_groups_0|to_yaml
        - debug:
            var: nv_groups|to_yaml
        - debug:
            var: nv_hosts|to_yaml
        - debug:
            var: nv_files
        - debug:
            var: nv_files_groups
        - debug:
            var: nv_files_dict
        - debug:
            var: nv_files_list|to_yaml
      run_once: true
      when: debug|d(false)|bool

    - include_vars: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ nv_files_list|
                selectattr('groups', 'subset', nv_hosts[inventory_hostname])|
                map(attribute='file')|list }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: groups|to_yaml
      run_once: true
      when: display_groups_native|d(false)|bool

    - debug:
        var: test_var
```

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all/nv_hosts.yml 
nv_inv: "{{ lookup('file', 'hosts')|from_yaml }}"
nv_groups_0_keys: "{{ nv_inv|json_query('keys(@)') }}"
nv_groups_0_vals: "{{ nv_inv|json_query('*.children[].*.keys(hosts)')|map('flatten') }}"
nv_groups_0: "{{ dict(nv_groups_0_keys|zip(nv_groups_0_vals)) }}"
nv_groups: "{{ groups|combine(nv_groups_0) }}"
nv_hosts_str: |
  {% for h in nv_groups.all %}
  {{ h }}: {{ nv_groups|dict2items|selectattr('value', 'contains', h)|map(attribute='key')|sort }}
  {% endfor %}
nv_hosts: "{{ nv_hosts_str|from_yaml }}"
```

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all/nv_files.yml 
nv_glob: "{{ playbook_dir }}/nested_vars/*.yml"
nv_files: "{{ query('fileglob', nv_glob) }}"
nv_files_groups: "{{ nv_files|map('basename')|map('splitext')|map('first')|map('split', '-') }}"
nv_files_dict: "{{ dict(nv_files|zip(nv_files_groups)) }}"
nv_files_list: "{{ nv_files_dict|dict2items(key_name='file', value_name='groups') }}"
```